# awk matching pattern in file

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I am stuck with awk

I have a file with the following structure

```
<package author=".." label=".." url="..">
<package author=".." label=".." url="..">
...
<package author=".." label=".." url="..">
```

as an output I want to get the list of only **url**'s

How to do it with awk.

I   thought it should be something like

```
awk '/url="(.*)"/{print $0}' 123
```

However it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: `I am stuck with awk` -- Could you tell us how you are stuck?  What did you try thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the `url` value, `grep` can be your friend:

```
$ cat a
<package author=".." label=".." url="thisis an url">
<package author=".." label=".." url="hello">
$ grep -Po '(?<=url=\")[^"]+' a
thisis an url
hello
```

This will show everything contained from `url="` (not included) until a double quote `"` is found.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*url="([^"]+).*/,"\\1","")}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

your `awk` command only filters the lines that contain the given pattern (`url=...`); since all your lines contain the string, it will give you all the lines.
in order to extract the information, you could do something like splitting up the 4th column along the double-quotes, e.g.:

```
awk '/url="(.*)"/{split($4, A, "\""); print A[2]}'
```

using `sed` is probably much easier:

```
sed -e 's|^.*url="\([^"]*\)".*$|\1|g'
```

Comment: This can be shorten some `awk '/url/{split($4, A, "\""); print A[2]}'`

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
cat file
<package author=".." label=".." url="https://www.cisco.com">
<package author=".." label=".." url="http://www.google.com/search">

awk -F\" '/url/ {print $2}' RS=" " file
https://www.cisco.com
http://www.google.com/search
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/url=\"([^\"]*)\"/)' your_file
```